# problems with retrieving the value of a class pointer object member allocated with operator new inside a function

Tags: c++, class, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm having problem with the following code. I try to fill in a member of an object called `station` inside a function, but I cannot retrieve it in `main()`.

This is my header `foo.h`

```
class DirectoryProperties
{
public:
    size_t      numberOfFolders;

    void        initialize_stations( StationBase *station );

private:
    void        fill_station_names( StationBase *station );
};

class StationInfo
{
public:
    std::string     name;
};
```

And this is my `foo.cpp`

```
#include "foo.h"

void DirectoryProperties::fill_station_names( StationBase *station )
{
    station[0].name = "dummy";
}

void DirectoryProperties::initialize_stations( StationBase *station )
{
    size_t N = 1;

    station = new StationBase[ N ];

    this->fill_station_names( station );

    // this works
    std::cout << station[0].stationName << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    DirectoryProperties dirInfo;

    StationBase *station = NULL;

    dirInfo.initialize_stations( station );

    // breaks here
    std::cout << station[0].stationName << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So, I can correcly print `station[0].name` inside `DirectoryProperties::initialize_stations( StationBase *station )`, but no in `main()`.

It also breaks if I try

```
int main()
{
    DirectoryProperties dirInfo;

    StationBase *station = NULL;

    dirInfo.initialize_stations( station );

    // breaks here
    station[0].stationName = "dummy";

    return 0;
}
```

So I assume that object pointer `station` has no memory allocated in `main`.

Comment: There are about 900 duplicates of this question, all of them crap!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`station` is a local variable in `initialize_stations`, so no changes to it have an effect outside of the function.

An immediate fix is to have the function return a pointer to the newed array.

```
StationBase* DirectoryProperties::initialize_stations(  )
{
  ....
  StationBase* station = new StationBase[ N ];
  ....
  return station;
}
```

A better solution is to return an `std::vector<StationBase>`. Or just a single `StationBase`, since you're only allocating one object anyway.

```
std::vector<stationBase> DirectoryProperties::initialize_stations()
{
    size_t N = 1;
    std::vector<stationBase> station(N);
    fill_station_names( station );
    return station;
}
```

and fix `fill_station_names` accordingly.

Comment: thank you. Just to let you know, in order to make the second solution work, I had to define "copy constructor" and "operator =" for class StationBase. Otherwise, it wouldn't compile.